# How do I revoke a permission from my app?

Tags: android, permissions, crash

I'm working on a version of the app called ["BlackBox"](https://github.com/3298837796/BlackBox), but I'm encountering the following problem: when giving the app a location permission, any app that uses location crashes. if it is revoked, the app asks for permission and works normally until closed and reopened

Would it be possible to revoke the permission when the app is closed? or something similar? (Android 7.1.1 without Google API support)

Comment: As far I know, from android 13 we can use ```revokeSelfPermissionOnKill ```. Not sure with Android 7.

Comment: @Kamal Sorry for the delay in responding, it doesn't work on Android 7